# Finding a particular solution for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2R}{\mathrm{d}r^2}+\frac1r\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}r}+\alpha^2R=J_0(\alpha r)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, bessel-functions

**Motivation**

I have the following non-homogeneous Bessel differential equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2R}{\mathrm{d}r^2}+\frac1r\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}r}+\alpha^2R=J_0(\alpha r)$$

I want to find the general solution for this ODE. I know that the general solution can be written as

$$R=R_h+R_p$$

where $R_h$ is the basis for the homogeneous ODE and is known to be

$$R_h=C_1 \, J_0(\alpha r) + C_2 \, Y_0(\alpha r).$$

Next, for finding the particular solution $R_p$ one can use the method of **variation of parameters** to obtain a particular solution using the homogeneous ones. However, this will lead to some messy solution with **hard integrals**! As the **MAPLE** or **WOLFRAM** both use this technique their result is not valuable for me. I know that

$$R_p=\frac1{2 \alpha^2}\left[\alpha rJ_1(\alpha r)\right] \tag{*}$$

and it can be verified by putting it into the ODE. In fact, I saw this in some published paper.

---

**Question**

Is there an **elegant** method to obtain such a particular solution mentioned in $(*)$?

Comment: The form of the solution is somehow suggested by the recurrence realtions of the bessel functions. I think u might build up proof out of them

Comment: @tired: Thanks for the hint, will think on that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the equation
$$
            \frac{d^2}{dr^2}J_{0}(\alpha r)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}J_{0}(\alpha r)+\alpha^2J_{0}(\alpha r)=0.
$$
$J_0$ has an everywhere convergent power series. So you can differentiate with respect to $\alpha$, and interchange orders of differentiation:
$$
             \frac{d^2}{dr^2}(rJ_{0}'(\alpha r))+\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(rJ_0'(\alpha r))+\alpha^2(rJ_0'(\alpha r))+2\alpha J_{0}(\alpha r)=0.
$$
Therefore $R(r)=-\frac{r}{2\alpha}J_{0}'(\alpha r)=-\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}(\alpha r)J_{0}'(\alpha r)$ is a solution of
$$
                   R''(r)+\frac{1}{r}R'(r)+\alpha^2R(r)=J_0(\alpha r).
$$

Comment: (+1) This is the **elegant** answer I was looking for! :) Many many thanks. So this technique can be used when ever the RHS of ODE is the  solution of the homogeneous ODE! :) Nice technique! Have you seen it before? :)

Comment: @H.R. : You're welcome. If you use fixed endpoint conditions, then the classical eigenfunction solutions always vary analytically with the eigenvalue parameter $\lambda$. There is a hidden condition on $J_0$, but the trivial condition is $J_0(\alpha r)|_{r=0}=1$ for all $\alpha$; the hidden condition has to do with an asymptotic behavior at $r=0$, and is always $0$. In fact $J_0(\sqrt{\lambda}r)$ must be an entire function of $\lambda$ because $L_0J_(\sqrt{\lambda}r)=\lambda J_{0}(\sqrt{\lambda}r)$, which it is because of the even powers in the power series expansion.

Comment: @TrialAndError Congratulate, your technique is impressive! Really,
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}(-rJ_1(\alpha r))+ \dfrac1r \dfrac d{dr}(-rJ_1(\alpha r))+\alpha^2(-rJ_1(\alpha r)) + 2\alpha J_0(\alpha r)=0,\quad$$
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}\left(\dfrac r{2\alpha}J_1(\alpha r)\right) + \dfrac1r \dfrac d{dr}\left(\dfrac r{2\alpha}J_1(\alpha r)\right)+\alpha^2\left(\dfrac r{2\alpha}J_1(\alpha r)\right) = J_0(\alpha r).$$

Comment: Human vs MAPLE & WOLFRAM - 2:0 ;)

Comment: This is a "resonant" non-homogenuous case, so that technique successful isn't accidental.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Yeah, Human is the Winner! :D

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov : I'm glad you think I'm a human. Machines win again.

Comment: TrialAndError :)

Answer (score 3):

Using variation of the constant method. Looking for the solution in the form
$$R_p = C(r)J_0(\alpha r),$$
then 
$$\dfrac d{dr}R_p = \dfrac d{dr}C(r)J_0(\alpha r) + C(r)\dfrac d{dr}J_0(\alpha r),$$
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}R_p = \dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}C(r)J_0(\alpha r) + 2\dfrac d{dr}C(r)\dfrac d{dr}J_0(\alpha r) + C(r)\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}J_0(\alpha r).$$
Substitution to non-homogenius equation gives:
$$J_0(\alpha r)\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}C(r) + \left(2\dfrac{d}{dr}J_0(\alpha r)+\dfrac1rJ_0(\alpha r)\right)\dfrac{d}{dr}C(r) + \left(\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}J_0(\alpha r)+\dfrac1r\dfrac d{dr}J_0(\alpha r)+\alpha^2J_0(\alpha r)\right)C(r) = J_0(\alpha r),$$
$$J_0(\alpha r)\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}C(r) + \left(\dfrac1rJ_0(\alpha r) + 2\dfrac d{dr}J_0(\alpha r)\right)\dfrac{d}{dr}C(r) = J_0(\alpha r),$$
Do substitution:
$$D(r)=\dfrac{d}{dr}C(r),$$
then
$$J_0(\alpha r)\dfrac{d}{dr}D(r) + \dfrac1rJ_0(\alpha r)D(r) + 2\dfrac d{dr}J_0(\alpha r)D(r) = J_0(\alpha r),$$
$$J_0^2(\alpha r)D(r) + 2rJ_0(\alpha r)\dfrac d{dr}J_0(\alpha r)D(r) + rJ_0^2(\alpha r)\dfrac{d}{dr}D(r) = rJ_0^2(\alpha r),$$
$$\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(rJ_0^2(\alpha r)D(r)\right) = rJ_0^2(\alpha r)$$
Use the formula $\int zJ_0^2(z)dz = \dfrac{z^2}2\left(J_0^2(z)+J_1^2(z)\right):$
$$rJ_0^2(\alpha r)D(r) = \dfrac{r^2}{2}\left(J_0^2(\alpha r)+J_1^2(\alpha r)\right),$$
$$D(r) = \dfrac{r}{2}\dfrac{J_1^2(\alpha r)+J_1^2(\alpha r)}{J_0^2(\alpha r)},$$
$$\dfrac d{dr}C(r) = \dfrac1{2\alpha}\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{rJ_1(\alpha r)}{J_0(\alpha r)}\right),$$
where
$$\dfrac{dJ_0(\alpha r)}{dr}=-\alpha J_1(\alpha r),\quad \dfrac{dJ_1(\alpha r)}{dr}=\alpha\left(J_0(\alpha r)-\dfrac1{\alpha r}J_1(\alpha r)\right)$$

$$C(r) = \dfrac r{2\alpha}\dfrac{J_1(\alpha r)}{J_0(\alpha r)},$$
$$\boxed{R_p = \dfrac r{2\alpha}J_1(\alpha r)}$$

And the same way for $Y_0(\alpha r).$

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. :) But why MAPLE or WOLFRAM is not able to do this! I don't know! :)

Comment: Because the handmade is the handmade... No problem, contact! :)

Comment: You did the technique of the variation of parameters but you also did some heuristic things in between by determining some exact differentials. I think those softwares just use the general formula for variation of parameters technique that we all know about it. :)

Comment: Can you take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562374/dual-bases-finite-versus-infinite-dimensional-spaces) too. Many thanks. :)

Comment: The first One integral I've found in the "Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions", but the second was hard. No doubt it's solvable but I hurry doing that in time.

Comment: OK, take your time. Waiting to see your answer there. :)

Comment: A little bit later. I've registered there just yesterday, and this is already the second hard analytics, the first was that: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567441/how-to-evaluate-int-01-costx-over-sqrt1x2dx/1567944#1567944

Comment: OK, see you tomorrow!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that nice answer there too. :) OK, see you then. Good Luck. :)